# GCC optimization missed opportunity

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, assembly, x86

I'm compiling this C code:

```
int mode; // use aa if true, else bb
int aa[2];
int bb[2];

inline int auto0() { return mode ? aa[0] : bb[0]; }
inline int auto1() { return mode ? aa[1] : bb[1]; }

int slow() { return auto1() - auto0(); }
int fast() { return mode ? aa[1] - aa[0] : bb[1] - bb[0]; }
```

Both `slow()` and `fast()` functions are meant to do the same thing, though `fast()` does it with one branch statement instead of two.  I wanted to check if GCC would collapse the two branches into one.  I've tried this with GCC 4.4 and 4.7, with various levels of optimization such as -O2, -O3, -Os, and -Ofast.  It always gives the same strange results:

**slow():**

```
        movl    mode(%rip), %ecx
        testl   %ecx, %ecx
        je      .L10

        movl    aa+4(%rip), %eax
        movl    aa(%rip), %edx
        subl    %edx, %eax
        ret
.L10:
        movl    bb+4(%rip), %eax
        movl    bb(%rip), %edx
        subl    %edx, %eax
        ret
```

**fast():**

```
        movl    mode(%rip), %esi
        testl   %esi, %esi
        jne     .L18

        movl    bb+4(%rip), %eax
        subl    bb(%rip), %eax
        ret
.L18:
        movl    aa+4(%rip), %eax
        subl    aa(%rip), %eax
        ret
```

Indeed, only one branch is generated in each function.  However, `slow()` seems to be inferior in a surprising way: it uses one extra load in each branch, for `aa[0]` and `bb[0]`.  The `fast()` code uses them straight from memory in the `subl`s without loading them into a register first.  So `slow()` uses one extra register and one extra instruction per call.

A simple micro-benchmark shows that calling `fast()` one billion times takes 0.7 seconds, vs. 1.1 seconds for `slow()`.  I'm using a Xeon E5-2690 at 2.9 GHz.

Why should this be?  Can you tweak my source code somehow so that GCC does a better job?

Edit: here are the results with clang 4.2 on Mac OS:

**slow():**

```
        movq    _aa@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax   ; rax = aa (both ints at once)
        movq    _bb@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rcx   ; rcx = bb
        movq    _mode@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rdx ; rdx = mode
        cmpl    $0, (%rdx)                 ; mode == 0 ?
        leaq    4(%rcx), %rdx              ; rdx = bb[1]
        cmovneq %rax, %rcx                 ; if (mode != 0) rcx = aa
        leaq    4(%rax), %rax              ; rax = aa[1]
        cmoveq  %rdx, %rax                 ; if (mode == 0) rax = bb
        movl    (%rax), %eax               ; eax = xx[1]
        subl    (%rcx), %eax               ; eax -= xx[0]
```

**fast():**

```
        movq    _mode@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax ; rax = mode
        cmpl    $0, (%rax)                 ; mode == 0 ?
        je      LBB1_2                     ; if (mode != 0) {
        movq    _aa@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rcx   ;   rcx = aa
        jmp     LBB1_3                     ; } else {
LBB1_2:                                    ; // (mode == 0)
        movq    _bb@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rcx   ;   rcx = bb
LBB1_3:                                    ; }
        movl    4(%rcx), %eax              ; eax = xx[1]
        subl    (%rcx), %eax               ; eax -= xx[0]
```

Interesting: clang generates branchless conditionals for `slow()` but one branch for `fast()`!  On the other hand, `slow()` does three loads (two of which are speculative, one will be unnecessary) vs. two for `fast()`.  The `fast()` implementation is more "obvious," and as with GCC it's shorter and uses one less register.

GCC 4.7 on Mac OS generally suffers the same issue as on Linux.  Yet it uses the same "load 8 bytes then twice extract 4 bytes" pattern as Clang on Mac OS.  That's sort of interesting, but not very relevant, as the original issue of emitting `subl` with two registers rather than one memory and one register is the same on either platform for GCC.

Comment: Is it only "slow" in disassembly or have you profiled it?  The two versions may have equivalent performance on a modern CPU.  Since you're on x86_64 you can't use `-march=` to try older cores (a certain base level of functionality is assumed in 64-bit).

Comment: A lot of this boils to the fact that while compilers are great at *optimizing* code, they rarely generate *optimal* code. After all, it's an NP-hard problem. So a lot of times, they don't even try to produce optimal code.

Comment: But to answer your question of why this happens, it seems that GCC doesn't try to do a final instruction merging pass.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see what clang does with it.

Comment: @BenJackson: Good point.  I have now profiled it and added the results at the end of the question.  The "slow" function is indeed much slower.

Comment: Declaring both auto, slow & fast static is out of the question? (It's not an answer but it would be good to see what code is generated then.)

Comment: I will say that I've seen this exact problem (unnecessary loads of operands than could be used directly from memory) when using SSE intrinsics in GCC and it seems to be due to argument order (e.g. addition commutes, but only the second argument of `_mm_add_*` will be considered as a possible memory operand).

Comment: @CharlieBurns: I added results from Clang, albeit on a different OS; I also verified that GCC has the same issue on Mac OS as on Linux.

Comment: @John, note that gcc also emits conditional moves, but only in auto0/1 which you didn't write here (at least it did for me, since auto0/1 still exist in their non-inlined form too). It seems that when inlining this code into slow, gcc removed that (or didn't write it in the first place), and clang didn't - maybe it has something to do with the stage at which inlining occurs. Can you try it with gcc -fearly-inlining ?

Comment: You might wish to compare to `int another(void) { const int *const ptr = (mode) ? aa : bb; return ptr[1] - ptr[0]; }`. It seems that having intermediates the compiler knows to be `const` helps generating better code, as does using pointers instead of conditionals.

Comment: How are you testing your microbenchmark on the Mac? Does the condition change unpredictably? The conditional-move is useful for truly unpredictable branches, but as soon as the branch predictor can do useful work, the jump is quite possibly more efficient.

Comment: @Leeor: `gcc -fearly-inlining` changed nothing at all.  @Nominal Animal: your `another()` also made no difference in the generated assembly.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I tried the micro-benchmark on the Mac just now.  I don't change the condition at all in there (it's simpler, it's one of the real-life situations, and GCC didn't emit conditional moves, so...).  Anyway, on the Mac, the performance is pretty much the same in all the combinations: slow()/fast(), gcc/clang, and mode=0/1.  I just call either fast() or slow() in a loop, 1 billion times, multiplying their result into an accumulator so the compiler won't get clever and optimize out the calls.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reason is that in the initial intermediate code, emitted for `slow()`, the memory load and the subtraction are in different basic blocks:

```
slow ()
{
  int D.1405;
  int mode.3;
  int D.1402;
  int D.1379;

  # BLOCK 2 freq:10000
  mode.3_5 = mode;
  if (mode.3_5 != 0)
    goto <bb 3>;
  else
    goto <bb 4>;

  # BLOCK 3 freq:5000
  D.1402_6 = aa[1];
  D.1405_10 = aa[0];
  goto <bb 5>;

  # BLOCK 4 freq:5000
  D.1402_7 = bb[1];
  D.1405_11 = bb[0];

  # BLOCK 5 freq:10000
  D.1379_3 = D.1402_17 - D.1405_12;
  return D.1379_3;
}
```

whereas in `fast()` they are in the same basic block:

```
fast ()
{
  int D.1377;
  int D.1376;
  int D.1374;
  int D.1373;
  int mode.1;
  int D.1368;

  # BLOCK 2 freq:10000
  mode.1_2 = mode;
  if (mode.1_2 != 0)
    goto <bb 3>;
  else
    goto <bb 4>;

  # BLOCK 3 freq:3900
  D.1373_3 = aa[1];
  D.1374_4 = aa[0];
  D.1368_5 = D.1373_3 - D.1374_4;
  goto <bb 5>;

  # BLOCK 4 freq:6100
  D.1376_6 = bb[1];
  D.1377_7 = bb[0];
  D.1368_8 = D.1376_6 - D.1377_7;

  # BLOCK 5 freq:10000
  return D.1368_1;
}
```

GCC relies on instruction combining pass to handle cases like this (i.e. apparently not on the peephole optimization pass) and combining works on the scope of a basic block. That's why the subtraction and load are combined in a single insn in `fast()` and they aren't even considered for combining in `slow()`.

Later, in the basic block reordering pass, the subtraction in `slow()` is duplicated and moved into the basic blocks, which contain the loads. Now there's opportunity for the combiner to, well, combine the load and the subtraction, but unfortunately, the combiner pass is not run again (and perhaps it cannot be run that late in the compilation process with hard registers already allocated and stuff).

Comment: I'll upvote you if you state _how you created_ the above output. It's not preprocessed C source, nor the debug info in the assembly source.

Comment: @FrankH., heh, sorry, it's the output from `gcc -c -da -O2 slow.c`, it produces lots and lots of files with dumps of the state of the compile unit at each RTL optimization phase.

Comment: This! GCC could be made to produce much better code by rerunning various optimization passes at multiple points in the pipeline, but it would make builds take all day and only shave off one instruction here, one instruction there. It's a speed/quality trade off. As far as I know this one is not parameterized; presumably because it would take real work to implement and add lots of code to check corner cases and such.

Answer (score 9):

I don't have an answer as to why GCC is unable to optimize the code the way you want it to, but I have a way to re-organize your code to achieve similar performance. Instead of organizing your code the way you have done so in `slow()` or `fast()`, I would recommend that you define an inline function that returns either `aa` or `bb` based on `mode` without needing a branch:

```
inline int * xx () { static int *xx[] = { bb, aa }; return xx[!!mode]; }
inline int kwiky(int *xx) { return xx[1] - xx[0]; }
int kwik() { return kwiky(xx()); }
```

When compiled by GCC 4.7 with `-O3`:

```
    movl    mode, %edx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    testl   %edx, %edx
    setne   %al
    movl    xx.1369(,%eax,4), %edx
    movl    4(%edx), %eax
    subl    (%edx), %eax
    ret
```

With the definition of `xx()`, you can redefine `auto0()` and `auto1()` like so:

```
inline int auto0() { return xx()[0]; }
inline int auto1() { return xx()[1]; }
```

And, from this, you should see that `slow()` now compiles into code similar or identical to `kwik()`.

Comment: Thanks for that.  A quick test showed the performance is better than either slow() or fast().  However, I don't think I can use this solution because in my real code things are slightly more complex (duh), and `aa` is actually a pair of functions rather than plain integers.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I updated the answer to show how the `xx()` function lets you redefine `auto0()` and `auto1()` to make `slow()` faster than `fast()`.

Comment: I don't quite follow...`xx()` still contains a pointer to `int aa[2]` but in my real code I need to call `aa0()` and `aa1()` for each access.  `int bb[2]` is really an array, but I don't see how to choose between e.g. `aa0()` and `bb[0]` using your approach.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Oh sorry, I am still answering your posted question. I can't speak to your real code, since there is nothing in your question about it.

Comment: In the real code, `auto0()` is like `{ return mode ? aa0() : bb[0]; }`.  And similar for `auto1()`.  This complicates the example somewhat, but GCC makes the same "mistake" in optimizing, with an extra instruction and an extra register used in `slow()`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Are `aa0()` and `aa1()` compute intensive? How often is `mode` switched, and what is `mode`'s expected value?

Comment: No, they're fairly simple functions (but not completely trivial).  Mode is 0 more often than not, meaning we use bb.  It's switched on some rather unknown schedule, but not nearly every call: mode could remain the same for an entire program run, or it could switch every few calls (switching just once or twice is unlikely).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to modify internals compilers parameters (--param name=value in man page). Those are not changed with any optimizations level (with three minor excepts).

Some of them control code reduction/deduplication.

For some optimizations in this section you can read things like « larger values can exponentially increase compilation time » .